# File with no \n split into lines fails to break evenly when encountering accented characters

Tags: sed, utf-8, split

I have a script which splits a UTF-8 stream of text into lines of 450 or 350 bytes

```
    FileType=`head -c 2 ${OutTemp}`
    
    if [ "$FileType" == "00" ] 
    then
        {
         sed -e 's/.\{450\}/&\n/g' ${OutTemp} > ${OutFile}
         }
    else
        {
        sed -e 's/.\{350\}/&\n/g' ${OutTemp} > ${OutFile}
        }
    fi
```

This works fine until it sees an accented character, for example it only sees é as half a character and then splits the rest of the stream incorrectly as the offset is now wrong by 1 character

Thus when I check for filetype after seeing an accented character, I get the last character of the previous line, not the part which should be the line identifier

```
0058091444033140919580126126211110110De Wit                   Viviane Helma                                         Voorveldstraat           26
0052031114655110319520126126211130130Dehertoghe               Eliane Josée                                         Kapellelaan              145
030051319481130519300126126211141141Delée                   Paula Josephina                                        Godshuisstraat           35
```

As you see, once it sees Josée it 'loses' a character and the offset is now wrong.

I tried converting the file to ISO-8859-1 or ASCII using Iconv, but the result is the same.

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 IN200617.AAH -o IN200617.CLA
```

I'm thinking there must be a way to get sed to recognise the UTF-8 settings but alas my skills are very limited in this area.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: The script that runs is defined as #!/bin/bash and am running GNU Sed 4.2.2

Comment: Can't reproduce with GNU sed 4.7. Could it be a bug in the version you have?

Comment: Could you check the value of `é`. In Unicode it could be 1 codepoint/character [not byte] or 2 codepoint/characters (and also more then 2 characters). If you should never split a string in the middle of combining chars. AKA: `sed` may not be the best tools to handle generic UTF-8 files.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that indeed sed is not the right tool. I rewrote it using Perl instead

```
FileType=`head -c 2 ${OutTemp}`

if [ "$FileType" == "00" ] 
then
    {
     perl -pe 's/(.{450})/$1\n/g' ${OutTemp} > ${OutFile}
     }
else
    {
     perl -pe 's/(.{350})/$1\n/g' ${OutTemp} > ${OutFile}
    }
fi
```

Comment: More likely your locale settings are wrong, if indeed you are using GNU `sed`. The braces around the `then` and `else` blocks are completely superfluous.